# Can I have function types in Java's Enum like Swift?

Tags: java, swift, oop, enums

Is it possible to write an equivalent code in Java for the following swift code? In fact, I want to know if it's possible to have a case of functions inside Java's enum (X, Y in MyEnum)

```
enum MyEnum{
    case X((Int) -> String)
    case Y((Double) -> Int)
}
```

Comment: What is a use case for this? Why would you need it?

Comment: No; or rather, they can be functions, just not with different input and output types. All values in a Java enum are of the same type.

Comment: @AndyTurner  can't the value of enum be of an `Object` type?

Comment: @nafas enum values are `Object`s, as are instances of all reference types in Java. But they're not *plain* `Object`: for `enum MyEnum {X; Y}`, `MyEnum.X.getClass() == MyEnum.Y.getClass() == MyEnum.class`.

Comment: I second what Andy says. You could do something with reflection or method handles, but there would be no type safety. Doing it like this, each `case` would have a different interface, how would you abstract over such a thing? Why would it be useful? Maybe it's because I've never used swift, but can you show a use case?

Comment: It can be used to make your switch case factor things that the cases have in common. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j50mPzDMWVQ, uses it for implementing  a calculator; when he wants to switch between different types of functions (e.g. unary, binary, constant, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible (technically), but it might not be that useful, as creating a simple class, that consumes a `Function` instance.

As you might already know, in Java, the enums represent one or more constants of the same type, which could have their own properties - this include [`java.util.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) instances. However, these `Function` instances cannot be passed dynamically at Runtime, but should be rather set at compile time, so that the constant is created.

Of course, you could make each enum constant have a different typed `Function`, by just creating the enum's constructor Generic:

```
enum MyEnum {
    X((String x) -> "Hello"), Y((Double d) -> 1);

    Function<?, ?> function;

    MyEnum(Function<?, ?> function) {
        this.function = function;    
    }
}
```

This, however, is not quite useful (although it compiles just fine). The `Function` in `X` doesn't use it's `String` parameter and returns a fixed value. So does the one in `Y`.

I'd rather introduce two separate instances of the same class:

```
class Instance<T, U> {

    private Function<T, U> function;

    public Instance(Function<T, U> function) {
         this.function = function;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to dynamically pass a `Function` instance, instead of setting it at compile-time.

Comment: I never used Swift, but according to the section on [Associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html), the values of those parameters seem to be bound to something like "instances of enum values", not to the values themselves, and that would be impossible in Java (at least using enums).

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't; at least, not if you want the differing types to be available when you use the enum. All enum values have to have the same type.

When you want "enum" values to have heterogenous types, you could use a class with static final fields:

```
final class MyHeterogeneousEnum {
  private MyHeterogeneousEnum() {}  // Not instantiable.

  static final Function<Integer, String> X = ...;
  static final Function<Double, Integer> Y = ...;
}
```

which allows you to use the values with their full type information:

```
String s = MyHeterogeneousEnum.X.apply(123);
Integer i = MyHeterogeneousEnum.Y.apply(999.0);
```

Of course, you don't have useful methods like `name()`, or `values()` to iterate over the constants in this class, nor is it inherently serializable. You can make implement these yourself - but for `values()` you have to use wildcards in the return type, in order that all values can be returned:

```
static Iterable<Function<?, ?>> values() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(X, Y));
}
```

However, note that a `Function` with a wildcard input type parameter is pretty much useless: you can't actually pass anything into it (other than `null`); so the `values()` method has limited utility.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for sure you can, in java enums can be more that just constants... every one of it values can be an anonymous class (take a look to TimeUnit.class for example)

now, you can do somthing like:

```
interface IFunction {
    double getY(double x);
}


enum Function implements IFunction {
    LINE {
    @Override
    public double getY(double x) {
        return x;
    }
    },
    SINE {
    @Override
    public double getY(double x) {
        return Math.sin(x);
    }
    }
}
```

and then the implementation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(Function.LINE.getY(i));
        System.out.println(Function.SINE.getY(i));
    }
}
```